# In SQL, group user actions by first-time or recurring

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

Imagine a sequence of actions. Each action is of a certain type.

Grouping by a given time-frame (e.g. day), how many of these actions happened for the first time, and how many were recurring?

**Example Input:**

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
| user_id   | action_type |     timestamp     |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
|     5     |    play     |  2014-02-02 00:55 |
|     2     |    sleep    |  2014-02-02 00:52 |
|     5     |    play     |  2014-02-02 00:42 |
|     5     |    eat      |  2014-02-02 00:31 |
|     3     |    eat      |  2014-02-02 00:19 |
|     2     |    eat      |  2014-02-01 23:52 |
|     3     |    play     |  2014-02-01 23:50 |
|     2     |    play     |  2014-02-01 23:48 |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+
```

**Example Output**

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
| first_time | recurring  |     day     |
+------------+------------+-------------+
|      4     |      1     |  2014-02-02 |
|      3     |      0     |  2014-02-01 |
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

**Explanation**

On 2014-02-02, users 2, 3, and 5 performed various different actions. There were 4 instances were the users performed an action for the first time; in one case the user 5 repeated the action 'play'.

Comment: I think the output should be `4 | 1 | 2014-02-02` On 2014-02-02, users 2, 3, and 5 performed various different actions. There were **4** instances were the users performed an action for the first time; in one case the user 5 repeated the action 'play'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I added a column 'Total Actions' because as I said, I believe there is a misinterpretation of facts in output example. You can remove it easily.</strike>

[TEST](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f91b7) in SQLFiddle.com for SQL Server 2008.

```
select      
    COUNT(q.repetitions) 'first time',
    SUM(case when q.repetitions>1 then q.repetitions-1 else 0 end) as 'recurring',
    day
from (
select COUNT(i.action_type) as 'repetitions',convert(date,i.time_stamp) as 'day'  
from input i
group by i.user_id, i.action_type,convert(date,i.time_stamp)

) q
group by q.day
order  by day desc
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. Maybe it should be "case when q.repetitions>1 then q.repetitions-1 else 0 end" ?

Comment: Why do you think that? Now that I see your edit, I'll remove 'Total Actions' column. If you have any doubt add some data sample and lets check it. Let me know

Comment: If user_id 5 would play 10 times on 2014-02-02, then I'd want that to show up as 9 recurring and 1 first-time. — More importantly, thank you for your fast and great help, Horaciux!

Comment: I misread the question, and deleted my earlier answer. To specifically tell which is new and which is recurring, you DO need a subquery along these lines. Grouping and running it by day is not a good way to do it though. You'd probably be better having the subquery select all action_types of all users ordered by time_stamp ASC and LIMIT 1, and then compare those timestamps against the date range you're requesting.

Comment: @joshstrike I can't see what you are pointing at. Please fell free to add some data sample you think that will make this query fail. and past the link.

Comment: @Horaciux I'm not saying it would fail, just that it's very inefficient for a subquery to SELECT COUNT() on the larger table. The only information he asked for was whether an action was new or repeated. For that, the subquery just needs to select anything prior to today LIMIT 1 which would be proof that it had happened before. If we did need to know how many of each action was done, a join with grouping by date would probably be faster than a seperate select in the FROM clause.

Comment: Depending on what's needed, too... you might just avoid the subquery altogether: SELECT user_id, action_type, MIN(timestamp) BETWEEN $firstdate AND $seconddate AS never_happened_before, COUNT(timestamp) AS totaltimes FROM actions GROUP BY user_id, action_type;